# it should remove the item in list number 3?

Tags: dart

I want to know how this work it should remove the item in list number 3 which is 'four' and print 'one','two','Three' why it is print three, four

here is the code:

```dart
final numbers = <String>['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
numbers.removeWhere((item) => item.length == 3);
print(numbers); // [three, four]`
```

Comment: If you want to remove `three` which is in index 2, you can do `numbers.removeAt(2);` Or `numbers.removeWhere((item) => item=="three" );`

Comment: I want to understand what remove where do and how it print these two number?

Comment: `removeWhere` will go through the list and find the matched item, means where we do our logic and return `true`. you can see `item.length==3`  is true for *'one' and 'two'* because its string length is 3, thats why these elements are removed.  You can find more on [List](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-core/List-class.html)

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2):

> [`removeWhere`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-core/List/removeWhere.html) :Removes all objects from this list that satisfy test.
> An object o satisfies test if test(o) is true.

`removeWhere` will go through the list and find the matched item, means where we do our logic and return true.

You can see `item.length==3` is true for 'one' and 'two' because its string length is 3, that's why these elements are removed. You can find more on [`List`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-core/List-class.html)

You can expand the method like

```dart
numbers.removeWhere((item) {
  bool isItemContains3Char = item.length == 3;
  print("${isItemContains3Char}  : $item  length : ${item.length}");
  return isItemContains3Char;
});
```

All you need to return `true` based on your logic from `removeWhere` to remove elements.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
 final numbers = <String>['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
  numbers.removeAt(2);
  print(numbers);


output 
[one, two, four]
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?